# Media Player is player multiple sounds and text view not showing right text

Tags: android

I am creating an application in which I have multiple images,sounds and texts.I want to show single image on a screen and for this I am using view pager and implementing on Page change Listener interface for keeping track of pages.But in my case images are scrolling as I want but I want to play sound according means each sound is different for every image in my case first 2 sounds are being played simultaneously and the text which is being set is in the array and it is getting second index position.I am unable to get the problem.Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.
Here is my code,

```
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter();
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(adapter);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

```
    Context context;
    MediaPlayer mp;
    private int[] mImages = new int[]{R.drawable.airplane,R.drawable.ambulance,R.drawable.apple,
            R.drawable.ball_img,R.drawable.bear_img,R.drawable.bird_img,
            R.drawable.cake_img,R.drawable.cat,R.drawable.car,R.drawable.clock,
            R.drawable.drum_img,R.drawable.dinasour,R.drawable.dog,R.drawable.dolphine,R.drawable.duck,
            R.drawable.eagle,R.drawable.elephant,
            R.drawable.fish,R.drawable.frog,
            R.drawable.horse,
            R.drawable.insect,
            R.drawable.jagular,
            R.drawable.kangroo ,
            R.drawable.lion,
            R.drawable.monkey,
            R.drawable.nose,
            R.drawable.owl ,
            R.drawable.peacock ,
            R.drawable.quill,
            R.drawable.rabit ,
            R.drawable.star ,
            R.drawable.tiger,
            R.drawable.umbrella ,
            R.drawable.vulture,
            R.drawable.wolf ,
            R.drawable.xylophone ,
            R.drawable.yoyo ,
            R.drawable.zebra
    };
    private int [] soundIds = {R.raw.airplane,R.raw.ambulance,R.raw.airplane,R.raw.ambulance,R.raw.airplane,R.raw.ambulance,R.raw.airplane,R.raw.ambulance};
    String description [] = {"Airplane","Ambulance","Apple","Ball","Bear","Bird","Cake","Cat","Car","Clock"
            ,"Drum","Dinasour","Dog","Dolphine","Duck","Eagle","Elephant","Fish","Frog","Horse","Insect"
            ,"Jagular","Kangroo","Lion","Monkey","Nose","Owl","Peacock","Quill","Rabbit","Star","Tiger"
            ,"Umbrella","Vulture","Wolf","Xylophone","Yoyo","Zebra"};

    public int getCount() {
        return mImages.length;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((ImageView) object);
    }
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container,int position) {

        context = ZoomedLetters.this;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) container.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        mp = MediaPlayer.create(context,soundIds[position]);
        mp.start();
        descriptions.setText(description[position]);
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
        int padding = context.getResources().
        getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.activity_vertical_margin);
        imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
        imageView.setImageResource(mImages[position]);
        ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
        return imageView;

        descriptions.setText(description[position]);

        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
        imageView.setImageResource(mImages[position]);
        ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
         return imageView;*/


    }

    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        if(mp.isPlaying()){
          mp.stop();
            mp.release();

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

    }
}
```

Comment: you just need to keep track of common index of the media and everything will work fine , hope the size of images,text, and sound are equal

Comment: The references of sound which I am keeping in an array are of different in size.Can it really cause a problem when I am explicitly stopping it in the method of on page selected?

Comment: yes it may cause issues since what i can undertstand from ur question is the at particaulr position , the unique text, image ,sound are shown, else handling position will be tedious task

Comment: Yeah,I got the solution thank you for your valuable time and suggestion. :)